# Two Different Chutzpah Visual Studio Extensions

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, chutzpah

What is the different between "Chutzpah Test Runner Context Menu Extension" and "Chutzpah Test Adapter for the Test Explorer"?

Info:
The Chutzpah is from Extensions in Visual Studio

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Chutzpah Test Runner Context Menu Extension* is a light weight extension that give you the ability to run test, coverage and debug on demand:

[image]

The *Chutzpah Test Adapter for Test Explorer* extension provides integration into the test explorer window in Visual Studio.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! does Does Chutzpah use source code from Sinon JS?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: If a new version of jasmine, mocha or qunit has been updated and these file are installed and located in the local computer, how should it be updated?

Comment: If I want to use the Qunit library from a VS solution project, and not the library at the local computer, is it possible to do it? Thank you!

Comment: Not yet, I have an feature request on Chutzpah to allow this but have not gotten to it yet.